# NSMutableDictionary setValue:forUndefinedKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-observing, kvc

I'm developing an iOS app. I have a class that extends NSObject that defines 1 property

```
//.h file
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *livedata; 


//.m file
if(self = [super init]){
    self.livedata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [self.livedata setValue:@"myvalue" forUndefinedKey:@"myUndefinedKey"];
}
```

I'm getting this error. 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:         '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myUndefinedKey.'

I've used NSMutableDictionary in the past for kvc, kvo. Yes I see the class is not kvc compliant.

Comment: You want `setValue:forKey` not `setValue:forUndefinedKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling a method that raises an exception when it is called. `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` is only called when `setValue:forKey:`, quoting [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/protocols/nskeyvaluecoding_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValue:forUndefinedKey:), finds no property for a given key. Instead, just call

```
[self.livedata setValue:@"myvalue" forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `setValue:forKey:` not `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`

```
[self.livedata setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

The system calls `setValue:forUndefinedKey` and the method is available to override.

From the Docs:
Invoked by `setValue:forKey:` when it finds no property for a given key.

"Subclasses can override this method to handle the request in some other way. The default implementation raises an `NSUndefinedKeyException`."